# need regex to match string that contains "http://" and ends with file extension from array

Tags: php, regex

looking for a php solution that will find a match the following expression:

1. URL contains "http://" (not necessarily begins with http://) AND
2. URL ends with a file extension from an array.

Example of file extension array

```
$filetypes = array(
jpg,
gif,
png,
js,
tif,
pdf,
doc,
xls,
xlsx,
etc);
```

Here is the working code I wish to update with the above requirements:

Right now, this code works and returns only URL's that contain "http://" but i want to include the second requirement as well.

```
$i = 0;
$matches = false;
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
        $i++;
        echo "[{$i}] {$value}<br>";
        $matches = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your sample url ?

Comment: `'http://mattressandmore.com/wp-content/themes/barberry/js/fresco.js'` - I just realised the file extension may end with apostrophe as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do an [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) call in your if statement  where you check with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) if the extension is in the `$filetypes` array.

```
$i = 0;
$matches = false;
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value) && in_array(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $filetypes)) {
        $i++;
        echo "[{$i}] {$value}<br>";
        $matches = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002760/need-regex-to-match-string-that-contains-http-and-ends-with-file-extension/30002780?noredirect=1#comment48124186_30002780) that a few url's contains single quotes you can just use this to get rid of them as [@Ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002760/need-regex-to-match-string-that-contains-http-and-ends-with-file-extension/30002780?noredirect=1#comment48124233_30002780) showed it in the comments:

```
trim($value, "'")
```

Then use it in the in_array() call as followed:

```
in_array(pathinfo(trim($value, "'"), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $filetypes)
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response, ill give it a go and report back

Comment: @user3436467 before we know it, Rizier has already completed your project piece by piece :D lol

Comment: works a treat! but i just realised some URLs contain apostrophe's at the end of the URL, anyway to easily factor this is instead of duplicating all items in the array with apostrophe ?

Comment: @user3436467 What do you mean with *some URLs contain apostrophe's* Can you make an example ?

Comment: here is an example `'http://mattressandmore.com/wp-content/themes/barberry/js/fresco.js'`

Comment: @user3436467 you can just `trim('string', "'")` those strings under the loop

Comment: @user3436467 So you mean that the quotes are part of the string?

Comment: yes, its part of the string but only for some URL's.. not all of them.. some bad web developers adding in the apostrophers :/

Comment: @user3436467 Then look at Ghost's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002760/need-regex-to-match-string-that-contains-http-and-ends-with-file-extension/30002780?noredirect=1#comment48124233_30002780

Comment: Instead of `preg_match`, you should use `strpos` here since you search a literal string.

Comment: @Ghost, i tried what you mentioned but didnt seem to work -- do i have it in the wrong place? see code http://www.pastebin.ca/2987401

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte As long as the regex doesn't expand and gets more complex it is for sure a way to go

Comment: @user3436467 yep you have it in the wrong place :) ^ See my updated answer to see where you have to put it!

Comment: @Rizier123, you are seriously awesome! hats off to you for being quick and thorough! thanks Ghost also for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution would be using just a simple regex:

```
$i = 0;
$matches = false;
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^http:\/\/.+\.(jpg|gif|png|js|tif|pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|etc)$/", $value)) {
        $i++;
        echo "[{$i}] {$value}<br>";
        $matches = true;
    }
}
```

This will ensure the match starts with http:// (due to the `^`) and ends with the .jpg or likewise (due to the or'ed list and `$`).

If you want to support https you could just use:

```
/^https?:\/\/.+\.(jpg|gif|png|js|tif|pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|etc)$/
```

Comment: Oh just read you're description again. Why is it, it shouldn't start with http? Is it not a requirement to end with the extension either then?